# Wiki software for documenting APIs

Tags: web-services, api, documentation, wiki, soa

What's an advisable way of documenting and sharing APIs (e.g. HTTP web-services)?

The requirements are:

- A Wiki type system in which anyone can edit any page.
- An easy way to write an API spec so that the styling/formatting is applied automatically, rather than having to manually add the styling for each individual page.

I would use [Wordpress](http://www.wordpress.com), except that it's not really a Wiki system; it's more of a blog engine. I want a nice, clean, structured hierarchy of pages, and the ability to **click and edit** instantly.

I tried [Google Sites](http://sites.google.com), but this also seems to be unsuitable, because it doesn't allow me to create a consistent style for APIs. The only control I have over styling is "themes", which change the look & feel of the whole site, and aren't specific enough.

I found a [hosted solution here](http://pbworks.com/content/API+Documentation?_kk=api%20documentation&_kt=fd785e1d-5b5b-4f2c-8c80-0db860205c9a), but at $499 p/year I'm sure we can do better.

Any suggestions?

Comment: +1. I asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129729/, and never got a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 2):

Many projects use [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/). Here is an example of a project that uses it http://djangobb.org/wiki

Trac integrates together wiki, issue tracking and source control.

Comment: +1 trac, it's great.  Although I miss proper mediawiki markup.

Comment: trac would do the job, but I've heard its a bit of a beast in terms of complexity.

Comment: Not sure why would people say so. In my experience it's easy to setup and integrate with Mercurial or Subversion. Usage and administration is very straightforward too.

Answer (score 0):

Might consider using something like doxygen to generate an inital snapshot and then just wikify that.

Comment: Would be elegant, but wouldn't work in this particular scenario, because we don't have control over the code for the back-end web-services. We're only developing the front-end of this system.

Comment: Wouldn't need to have the actual backend code necessarily. Could code up stubs in something like python, or some other doxygen compatible language.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was posted here also: [Wiki solution for APIs documentations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391658/)

and I suggested using [MindTouch](http://www.mindtouch.com/)

**jonathan, just saw your comment about trac adding too much complexity. you'll likely find the same with MindTouch, but that's because you're asking for a solution to a specific problem, and the suitable tools available offer much more capabilities (ie complexities)