# Wiki solution for APIs documentations?

Tags: api, wiki

I'm wondering if there is any Wiki solutions that perfectly fit an API documentation and let you nicely list the end points and parameters/responses.

Any recommandations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [MindTouch](http://www.mindtouch.com/). 
API Documentation is one of the ways the developer site http://developer.mindtouch.com makes use of the product

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to this question but definitely a good starting point to help you get answered:

I had the same questions and initially thought [PBWorks](http://pbworks.com/) since that's who Twitter originally used for [their API Wiki](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554648/FrontPage) and in the past I've used Google Sites (on the [Kwwika Wiki](http://wiki.kwwika.com)) since it's effectively a wiki.

I'm sure that if you want a more automated solution that will allow you to auto create your wiki from a build process then there will be solutions such as [Read the Docs](http://readthedocs.org/).

All this said I think a really good starting point is [WikiMatrix](http://www.wikimatrix.org/) and their Wiki Choice Wizard.